# How can I change the global option for the `str()` function in R?

Tags: r

I'd like to change the default display behavior of the `str` function in R.

I'd like strings to be truncated. For that purpose I use the argument `nchar.max = 30` when calling `str`, so that only 30 characters are shown.

I don't understand from the documentation how to get this with the `options()` command.

One thing I could do is change the value for the parameter `vec.len` with `options(str = strOptions(vec.len = 1))`

Can someone please tell me how to do this!

Comment: Would defining your own variation work? `my_str = function(...) str(..., nchar.max = 30)`?

Comment: You won't be able change `nchar.max` using options as its default is hard-coded as numeric 128, not something from `getOption(...)` or `strO$...`.

Comment: `nchar.max` is not an argument to `strOptions()`